# KotlinJS with React-Router-Dom, How to use the location state?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, react-router-dom, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a kotlin multiplatform project that has a jvm server and a KotlinJS client that uses [kotlin-wrappers](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers) such us kotlin-react and react-router-dom. I recently updated the wrappers version and they changed the way that the NavigateOptions' state works. Before, i had something like this:

```kotlin
navigate(to="/", options = object : NavigateOptions {
   override var replace: Boolean? = null,
   override var state: Any? = "..." // This string is the state i want to set
})
```

But now they have changed the state to a "LocationState" type and i can't find out how to use it.
I leave [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/blob/master/kotlin-history/src/main/generated/history/State.kt) a link to the new interface just in case it helps.

Comment: Did you ask directly in Github issues — https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/issues?